# Is there a "correct" way to use exported data internally in an R package?

Tags: r, devtools, package-development

I know that exported data (access to users) belongs in the `data/` folder and that internal data (data used internally by package functions) belongs in `R/sysdata.rda`. However, what about data I wish to both export to the user AND be available internally for use by package functions?

Currently, presumably due to the order in which objects/data are added to the `NAMESPACE`, my exported data is not available during `devtools::check()` and I am getting a NOTE: `no visible binding for global variable 'data_x'`.

There are probably a half dozen ways to get around this issue, many of which appear to me as rather hacky, so I was wondering if there was a "**correct**" way to have BOTH external and internal data (and avoid the NOTE from `R CMD check`).

So far I see these options:

- write an internal function that calls the data and use that everywhere internally
- Use the ':::' to access the data; which seems odd and invokes a different warning
- Have a copy of `data_x` in BOTH `data/` **and** `R/sysdata.rda` (super hacky)
- Get over it and ignore the `NOTE`

Any suggestions greatly appreciated,
Thx.

Comment: I think Hadley covers this [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html). I'm not sure but could calling it by `data` be enough?(this puts it in .Globalenv which AFAIK is not standard practice per CRAN policies).

Comment: I am familiar with Hadley's book, unfortunately (as far as I can tell) he describes either external or internal, but not both. Unless I've simply missed it. And yeah, I'm not a big fan of simply dumping objects into the user's global environment.

Comment: Check this [one](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html#data-sysdata) maybe? Suggests `devtools::use_data` which seems to be what you need per my understanding.

Comment: AFAIK `use_data()` has an `internal =` argument, which allows you to go with either the `sysdata.rda` OR the `*.rda` path, but not both. Also, I do believe this functionality was moved into the `usethis` package FYI ... `usethis::use_data()`.

Comment: I did find this thread, though it is by now quite old:
[r-devel](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-for-data-sets-in-a-package-td4696053.html)
Though it did not seem to come to any satisfactory conclusion on a "best" method.